# Kafka log compaction callback

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka log compactor, and I was wondering if there lis any call-back function that I can use to be invoked as a consumer, when the Kafka broker perform the log compaction of my Topic.

So far I cannot see any callback for this, so I was wondering what is the standard strategy to detect that log compaction took place.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The client itself has no communication with the broker for such events. In the past, we used Splunk to capture the compaction events from the LogCleaner process logs, and we could generate webhook events based on that, if we needed if for any reason (we only used it for administrative debugging and clients never needed it)

Comment: So there's no callback or official way to know when this happens. In another words, is better dont use log compactor as a mechanism that can be deterministic.

Comment: It can be used, but the clients are oblivious to it. 1) Consumers with no lag are reading from an active log segment, and active segments are never compacted 2) Compacted topics are used to build KTables or Hashmaps by reading from the very beginning of the topic, where older segments would have already been compacted, and newer events with the same keys override old ones. Therefore, I can't think of a use case where knowing if a compaction occurred would be useful for a client unless you're maintaining multiple data structures that you're trying to prune information out of